High resistivity silicon detector
How is the resistivity of the silicon detector is related with the depletion of the detector bulk? In a thesis I read that to achieve low full depletion voltage, a high resitivity silicon detector is required. Why?

To create the depletion region, you pull charged carriers out of the depletion layer, leaving behind the (fixed) charged donor or acceptor ion sites. In high-resistivity material there is less doping so there are less of those ions (and also less free carriers before you pull them out) which means:

You need less voltage to pull the carriers out of a depletion layer of certain width.
You end up with less charge remaining in the depletion layer (p-charge remaining in the n-material in the cathode and n-charge remaining in the p-material of the anode, of course!)
Therefore the electric field in the depletion region also will be lower.
Conversely, when using a given voltage you can create a larger-width depletion layer in low-doped material than in high-doped material.

Since there is only a finite region you want to deplete before you call it "full depletion", it is 1) and not 4) that is relevant for your question.
